# Is it possible to have multiple links in a single cell with MUI's DataGridPro

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
Batch | Date |    Subjects
  1     Mar 1  101, 102
  2     Mar 2  105, 106, 107 
  3     Mar 3  109
```

I need the values in the last column to be links, each pointing to a page for that subject.
The data is in an array, and when I use renderCell it clumps all the values together and creates a single link.

```
  {
    field: "subjects",
    headerName: "Subjects",
    width: 300,
    renderCell: (params) => (
      <Link to={`/cultures/${params.value}`}>{params.value}</Link>
    ),
  },
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out a solution. It works, but I am getting some error messages that do not impede the page from functioning.

I created my own function that I passed to `renderCell`, called `RenderLinks`

```
  {
    field: "subjects",
    headerName: "Cultures",
    width: 300,
    renderCell: RenderLinks,
  },
```

The function generates a React List component with the links available inside item buttons.

```js
const RenderLinks = ({ value }) => {
  return (
    <List style={flexContainer}>
      {value.map((id) => (
        <ListItemButton
          key={id}
          component={Link}
          to={`/subject/${id}`}
        >
          {id}
        </ListItemButton>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
};
```

This is the error message I now get:
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` supplied to `GridCell`, expected one of type [number, object, string, boolean].

The page loads and the component functions perfectly, allowing users to click the links and navigate to where I want them to go. The error is not critical, but I would still like to know how to fix it.